# В каком именно инпуте произошло изменение

Tags: jquery

У меня есть функция:

```
function updateIata(input) {
    input.siblings('span.iata-code').css({
        'top': '1px',
        'opacity': '0'
    });
    $.getJSON('/json/cities.json', function(data) {
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(data[i].name_translations.ru == input.val()) {
                input.siblings('span.iata-code').text(data[i].code).css({
                    'top': '10px',
                    'opacity': '1'
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

В теле которой производятся изменения, связанные со стилем инпута. Вызывается эта функция по событию `change`:

```
$('input.iata-updater').on('change', function(){
    updateIata($(this)); // нерабочий вариант
});
```

> ничего не передаётся в функцию .siblings() Cannot read property
>   'siblings' of undefined

Проблема в том, что у меня два инпута с таким классом. Как мне передать в функцию информацию о том, какой именно инпут был изменён?

Comment: "// нерабочий вариант" - чем это он не рабочий?

Comment: @Igor ничего не передаётся в функцию .siblings() `Cannot read property 'siblings' of undefined`

Answer (score 2):

> ничего не передаётся в функцию .siblings() Cannot read property
>   'siblings' of undefined

Не может быть. Вы где-то вызываете `updateIata` с неопределенным параметром (или без параметра). Или используете ее в качестве callback, куда вызывающий код ничего не передает.

Comment: Да, точно. Всё от невнимательности :(